# Converting a Dataframe into a specific json format

Tags: python, json, format

I need to convert this dataframe into the json format below and I can't get it to work

| conv_item_id | updated_item_value | order_check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1.99 | approved |
| b | 2.99 | approved |
| c | 2.99 | approved |

```
{
   "conversion_items":{
      "a":{
        "item_value":1.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "b":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "c":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    }
  }
}
```

I currently have this function that converts the dataframe into a string

```
# build all our requests
def build_request(row):   
    return {
        row["conv_item_id"]: {
                "item_value": row["updated_item_value"],
                "status" : str.lower(row["order_check"])
            }
        }

request_payload = df.apply(build_request, axis=1).to_json(orient='records')[1:-1].replace('}{', '} {')

df2 = {"conversion_items": request_payload}
```

gives the following result as a string

```
{'conversion_items': '{"a":{"item_value":1.99,"status":"approved"}},{"b":{"item_value":2.99,"status":"approved"}},{"c":{"item_value":2.99,"status":"approved"}}'}
```

I need the format to be

```
{'conversion_items': {"a":{"item_value":1.99,"status":"approved"},"b":{"item_value":2.99,"status":"approved"},"c":{"item_value":2.99,"status":"approved"}}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? I've attempted to use strip and replace but it either only removes the final } or all of them.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"conv_item_id":["a","b","c"],"updated_item_value":[1.99,2.99,2.99],"order_check":["approved"]*3})
```

- set index to conv_item_id using `df.set_index()`
- rename column names using `df.rename()`
- Convert df to dict with index as keys using `df.to_dict("index")`
- dump dict to json using `json.dumps()`

```
import json
df = df.set_index("conv_item_id")
df = df.rename(columns={"updated_item_value":"item_value","order_check":"status"})
out = json.dumps({"conversion_items": df.to_dict("index")})
print(out)

>> {'conversion_items': {'a': {'item_value': 1.99, 'status': 'approved'},
  'b': {'item_value': 2.99, 'status': 'approved'},
  'c': {'item_value': 2.99, 'status': 'approved'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invert your dataframe and get to_dict() method:

```
import pandas as pd

dict_test = {
   "conversion_items":{
      "a":{
        "item_value":1.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "b":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "c":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    }
  }
}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict_test['conversion_items'])
df = df.T
print(df)
```

| conv_item_id | updated_item_value | order_check |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1.99 | approved |
| b | 2.99 | approved |
| c | 2.99 | approved |

Now get the to_dict() method on the transposed dataframe:

```
{'conversion_items':df.T.to_dict()}
```

```
{
   "conversion_items":{
      "a":{
        "item_value":1.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "b":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    },
      "c":{
        "item_value":2.99,
        "status":"approved"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This also worked for the most part. Just had to change the index to conv_item_id.